# Atheros AR9485 works ONLY on live-media

Tags: settings, wifi, networking, keyboard

### MY SITUATION

Recently I decided I wanted to change OS my Samsung NP270E5E, as Windows 10 was getting considerably slow and stuttery and I need it to be smooth enough to let me work without hiccups.

As I had a bit of former experience with Linux, and as of right now I don't need big programs like Photoshop and similar, I opted for a ligth distro like Kubuntu, then Lubuntu, then Zorin OS and now Elementary OS. Why did I go through so many? Because on every and each one of the, I had the same exact problem and I couldn't manage to find a fix.

TL;DR
Laptop: Samsung NP270E5E
OS: Elementary OS 5.1 Hera

### THE PROBLEM

My wireless (wlan) card is not connecting to the internet. I have a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 that runs on the ath9k driver.

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lspci -v
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Expansion ROM at f1580000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

The thing is that **wireless WORKS when I use the Live Media on my bootable USB stick** (which I'm using rn to post this) and it goes flawlessy. Also, if I REBOOT from the live-media into my installed version of eOS (click restart, wait for the usb to being inactive, plug off the usb, the system boots into the hd) WiFi WORKS|

Same thing if I INSTALL any distro, it reboots and on the first session WIFi works, and if I keep rebooting it keeps working. (I noticed this because I've done it so many times).

*The problem occurs when I shut down the machine to boot it back up. In that case, the card is disabled.* (rfkill shows hard block for phy0, which is not hard blocked on the live media). When it is in this state, I have no way to turn it back up as the Fn-key combination for the hardware switch does not respond. (Which it does on the live-media).

I noticed that a behaviour connected to the WiFi working or not is the fact that congruently with the WiFi I can also turn it ON and OFF with my hardware switch (Fn+F12), which DOES NOT work when WiFi is disabled. (Same thing for brightness up and down)

### WHAT I'VE ALREADY DONE

- Tried different distros
- blacklisted acer_wmi: it did not work but on
  ONE boot-up after this WiFi seemed to work. I shut it down again to
  verify and boot it back up and it wasn't working again.
- Updated eOs
- As I noticed the problem might be related to the fact that I CANNOT
  turn the hardware switch on and off, I tried looking for the module
  on the live media that was handling this task. I found that on the
  live media a certain mxm_wmi was present that wasn't on the hd. Tried
  to modprobe that but didn't work.
- Same thing for nouveau because I
  had installed nVidia drivers, I removed them and I tried to use
  nouveau instead but it didn't work.
- I reset BIOS in every way
  possible. (Load default settings, CMOS removal)

### NOTES

On the live-media, there is a module called *sparse_keymap*, or something similar. Is that related to the Fn-key binding process?

WiFi card doesn't seem to have problems, as it works fine when it does. It looks like it's a software problem.

I've had problems with my BIOS. I can't get into it by pressing F2 (which is the key that Samsung states for this model), nor with other keys. Trust me I tried everything I could find on the internet. The only way I can get into it is by changing boot order through efibootmgr.

Also, I accidentally deleted the entry for the Hard Drive so when I boot into BIOS I can only see entries for USB, CD ROM and RECOVERY (and BOOT MENU). That's not an issue because it does boot into the operating system (as I set it up correctly on efibootmgr). But still, it's a bit messed up.

I really hope you can help me with this, I'd like to be able to use my pc without having to keep a USB stick in all the time.

P.S. If you need me to, I can post terminal outputs from both the working version (live-media) and the non-working one (hard-drive) to see the differences.